# How to substitute the first occurrence across the whole file?

Tags: substitute

I've file in which there are some repeated parts and I want to get rid of the first occurrence. Normally I'd do `%s/_exclude//` to perform substitute for all lines, however I want to replace only the first occurrence in the file, e.g. having:

```
name = foo
# unknown number of lines ...
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule1 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule2 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule3 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule4
```

I'd like to do remove first occurrence of `_exclude`, so it becomes:

```
name = foo
# unknown number of lines ...
features[rules_config][] = rule1 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule2 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule3 
features_exclude[rules_config][] = rule4
```

So if I repeat the action again, it'll remove the next one (on whichever line it is) and so on.

What's the easiest way of doing that?

Comment: According to [`:h :s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s) you can use a count after a substitute command like `:%s/_exclude// 1` but for a reason that I don't understand it begins with the last line of the range so it would have an action on `rule4`. Also you talk about removing the whole line but your substitute command only remove the word `_exclude` is it what you actually want? Finally wouldn't a search `/_exclude` followed by normal mode `dd` wouldn't be what you're looking for?

Comment: Removing only `_exclude` text, not the line.

Comment: you can do a substitution using line number if you know line numbers

Comment: @Raju I assume I won't be able to know the line numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25840884/1848140
try this

Comment: or may be this :%s/word/newword/gc asks for confirmation on every replacement.

Comment: @Raju Could work with confirmation, however in my case I'm planning to perform this action non-interactively one by one with Ex as shown in [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7201/467).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the method using pattern matches:

```
:/_exclude/s/_exclude//
```

It will first identify the line which has `_exclude`, then do the substitution on that line (`s/_exclude//`).

To repeat the last command-line change, use the `@:` command.

---

This can be simplified further more as per [@muru](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7194/how-to-substitute-the-first-occurrence-across-the-whole-file/7195#comment11821_7195) suggestion by:

```
:/_exclude/s///
```

since an empty pattern will use the previous pattern.

Comment: You can condense that to `:/_exclude/s///`. If given an empty pattern, `:s` will re-use the previous pattern, which, in this case would be `_exclude` from `:/`.